# does rails 3.1 download jquery and jquery ui files if specified in the asset pipeline?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

does rails 3.1 download jquery and jquery ui files if specified in the asset pipeline?
I have the gems installed and my application.js  is as below
Do I need to copy jquery manually into the pipeline?

gem file :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

#gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Depot31</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset pipeline takes care of this if you to add following lines into your Gemfile:

```
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

check [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/) and [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) for more information how to setup this gems

Comment: I just created a scaffold app with those instructions but I get a 'couldnt fine file jquery' error

Comment: please update your post with your gemfile, layout file and application.js, then I should be able to help

Comment: In application.js you have to replace jquery-ui with jquery.ui.all, you also have to follow instruction behind given link to setup jquery-ui css rules. But it is not what causes your error. I think you have to stop your server, then run "bundle install" and start server again.

Comment: Still the same error? I get this error on my app when I tried to run server without mentioned gems added to Gemfile. I don't have any more good ideas. Maybe try to use new version of rails, 3.1.0 is preety old, and may be buggy.